# C# implementation to get SignedCms from signed file

Tags: c#, c++, certificate, digital-signature

I am having an implementation using C++ CRYPT32.DLL to extract a SignedCms object from a signed c# assembly dll.

[image: signed c# assembly]

The certificate used to sign the dll is expired but has a valid certificate chain inside. The important thing is that the certificate consists of three certificates which I all want to extract.

[image: CertificateChain]

```
    private static readonly int CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE = 0x00000001;
    private static readonly int CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL = 0x00003ffe;
    private static readonly int CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL = 0x0000000e;
    private static readonly int CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE = 29;

    [DllImport("CRYPT32.DLL", EntryPoint = "CryptQueryObject", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CryptQueryObject(
        int dwObjectType,
        IntPtr pvObject,
        int dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
        int dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
        int dwFlags,
        IntPtr pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
        IntPtr pdwContentType,
        IntPtr pdwFormatType,
        IntPtr phCertStore,
        IntPtr phMsg,
        IntPtr ppvContext
    );

    [DllImport("crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CryptMsgGetParam(
        IntPtr hCryptMsg, int dwParamType, int dwIndex, IntPtr pvData, ref int pcbData );

    public static SignedCms GetSignedCmsFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        var pvObject = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(fileName);
        var phMessage = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
        var pvData = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            SignedCms signedCms = null;
            var success = CryptQueryObject(
                CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                pvObject,
                CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
                CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
                0,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                phMessage,
                IntPtr.Zero);

            if (success)
            {
                var hMessage = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(phMessage);
                var cbData = 0;
                success = CryptMsgGetParam(
                    hMessage,
                    CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE,
                    0,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    ref cbData);

                if (success)
                {
                    var data = new byte[cbData];
                    pvData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(byte) * data.Length);

                    success = CryptMsgGetParam(
                        hMessage,
                        CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE,
                        0,
                        pvData,
                        ref cbData);

                    if (success)
                    {
                        Marshal.Copy(pvData, data, 0, cbData);
                        signedCms = new SignedCms();

                        try
                        {
                            signedCms.Decode(data);
                            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName + ".export", data);
                        }
                        catch (CryptographicException)
                        {
                            signedCms = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return signedCms;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pvObject != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pvObject);

            if (phMessage != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(phMessage);

            if (pvData != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pvData);
        }
    }
```

The function works very well but since the crypt32.dll function is depricated I am looking for a pure C# implementation that is doing the same and provides the SignedCms object.

The closest what I could find so far is the X509Certificate.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName)
```

[CryptQueryObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject)

---

Solution

Thanks to the post below I could implement a pure C# method to extract the SignedCms.

The only thing that is not fitting perfectly is that the startindex is off by 8 bytes and the size is 10 bytes smaller.

```
    public static SignedCms GetSignedCmsFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        var result = new SignedCms();

        uint startIndex = 0;
        uint size = 0;

        var reader = new PeHeaderReader(fileName);
        if (reader.Is32BitHeader)
        {
            startIndex = reader.OptionalHeader32.CertificateTable.VirtualAddress;
            size = reader.OptionalHeader32.CertificateTable.Size;
        }
        else
        {
            startIndex = reader.OptionalHeader64.CertificateTable.VirtualAddress;
            size = reader.OptionalHeader64.CertificateTable.Size;
        }

        //var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName).Skip((int)startIndex).Take((int)size).ToArray();

        //Somehow the start index and size are not fitting perfectly and I have to adapt them
        var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName).Skip((int)startIndex + 8).Take((int)size - 10).ToArray();

        result.Decode(data);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: See Art's (last answer) on following posting.  He ask good question if you have the Win XP version without latest updates : https://superuser.com/questions/1349554/what-is-crypt32-in-windows-xp

Comment: Here is the same question on Microsoft Forums for reference https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/263d99c7-df3f-4aa9-9c04-470a3623e153/what-is-new-alternative-for-cryptqueryobject-because-it-is-deprecated

Comment: And one on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198741/cng-replacement-for-cryptqueryobject

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641809/how-to-validate-and-extract-pkcs7-file-content-on-windows-c-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a CNG equivalent of the call but here is the [specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Authenticode_PE.docx) which should let you extract the PKCS#7 which are the bytes for the SignedCms:

[image: Signature in executable]

The spec says:

> Authenticode signatures can be “embedded” in a Windows PE file, in a 
>   location specified by the Certificate Table entry in Optional Header
>   Data Directories

Here are nice overviews of the bytes in the PE header: 
- https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/presenting-the-pe-header/
- https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/

And almost all details: https://blog.kowalczyk.info/articles/pefileformat.html

On github I found a managed sample that reads the PE header: https://gist.github.com/augustoproiete/b51f29f74f5f5b2c59c39e47a8afc3a3

**EDIT**: The code on github was not reliable according to a comment of @martin-s and he succeeded with this alternative:

https://github.com/secana/PeNet

All pieces together should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I could implement it so that it works. The only thing that is not fitting perfectly is that the startindex is off by 8 bytes and the size is 10 bytes smaller in the PE Header class. Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Is it a MSIL, x86 or x64 compiled assembly?

Comment: Meanwhile I found the issue. It seems that the PE parser from the link you have provided is a bit buggy for this purpose. I found a different, newer implementation of a PE file parser on the net that is working without theses issues. https://github.com/secana/PeNet