# Verify signed DLL is signed by my certificate

Tags: certificate, signing

We have a .pfx and use the windows signtool to sign a DLL with it.  I want to programmatically verify that the DLL is signed with our certificate when I load it.  I use WinVerifyTrust, but that just verifies that is signed by a trusted publisher (I think).  To verify that it is signed with our certificate,  I think I should use CryptVerifyCertificateSignature.  How do I create the "BLOB" of "CERT_SIGNED_CONTENT_INFO" from my DLL to pass to this function?

Or... is there a better or easier way to verify that the DLL is signed with our cert?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: [C# implementation to get SignedCms from signed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242543/c-sharp-implementation-to-get-signedcms-from-signed-file/55414506#55414506)

If you would provide some more details - for instance programming language - the community would be able to help you further and answer more accurate :-)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Any language... Windows managed or unmanaged.  I've been around a long, long time, but this whole trust, signing, etc.  is a mystery to me

Comment: There is a Microsoft Support page illustration the WinAPI: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables